# Error trying to install the madmom package in python

Tags: python

When I try to install the `madmom` package I get the following error message:

```
Collecting madmom
  Using cached madmom-0.16.1.tar.gz (20.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-613iv819\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-613iv819\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-613iv819\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup  
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\vadim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-613iv819\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup  
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have already successfully installed all prerequisites, including `cython` which seems to be the problem. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried to install the package in a virtual environment and installed a different version of `cython`, but still no good.

Comment: Unsure what the issue is, but you shouldn't have to install the dependencies separately. pip should pull those in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem vanishes when installing from source:

`pip install git+https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom`

as described in [issue #528](https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom/issues/528#issuecomment-1712509288).

Generally, it's a good idea to provide your os and python version when reporting a problem.
In my case it was `macOS 14.0 Sonoma, Python 3.11.5` and installing from source as indicated above solved the problem.